# Comment traduire « computational propaganda » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, anglais, adjectifs, informatique

Dans une synthèse accompagnant une série d'[études](http://comprop.oii.ox.ac.uk/) on peut lire que :

> Computational propaganda is a term and phenomenon that encompasses
>   recent digital misinformation and manipulation efforts. *It is best
>   defined as the use of algorithms, automation, and human curation to
>   purposefully distribute misleading information over social media
>   networks* (Woolley & Howard, 2016). Computational propaganda involves
>   learning from and mimicking real people so as to manipulate public
>   opinion across a diverse range of platforms and device networks.
>
> [ [*Computational Propaganda Worldwide: Executive Summary*](http://comprop.oii.ox.ac.uk/wp-content/uploads/sites/89/2017/06/Casestudies-ExecutiveSummary.pdf) (2017), S. C.
>   Woolley, P. N. Howard, University of Oxford, p. 7, je souligne ]

---

Le terme *computationel* est connu (il s'agit de vocabulaire technique : [GDT](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8873687), [Termium+](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=COMPUTATIONAL&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs), qui donne en même temps *informatique, calculatoire, par ordinateur, algoristique*, dans un domaine particulier) en français alors qu'aux tout débuts de l'informatique on avait développé cet adjectif allant avec l'emprunt *computer*, avant de se mettre à utiliser le mot *ordinateur*, alors on le trouverait peut-être aujourd'hui dans certains noms de disciplines (sciences) et il serait peu fréquent (GDT). En anglais on trouve l'adjectif associé à *model* dans un [exemple](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/computational) ; autrement [on a lu](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/53779) que le champ sémantique de l'adjectif, pour « of, relating to, or using computers » (relié à l'informatique ou impliquant l'utlisation d'un ordinateur, si on a bien compris), serait moins vaste que celui de *computer/computing* à certains égards... On remarque que les auteurs ont choisi cet adjectif et non *computer, digital*, ou *internet* et on s'intéresse à comment se manifesterait en français la nuance de sens ou de [registre](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/dictionnaire/anglais/computational) que cet apport pourrait introduire.

---

Disposons-nous déjà d'une traduction formelle/normative ou autrement comment choisit-on de traduire la *computional propaganda* en français, en tenant compte de la définition de Woolley & Howard de 2016, du sens de l'adjectif, et de l'histoire du terme *computationnel* et de tout autre facteur qu'on jugera pertinent ; qu'est-ce qui motive ce choix et en assure la cohérence au lexique :

- L'adjectif *computationnel* est-il apte à signifier ce dont il s'agit [ou apte à jouer le même rôle que
  *computational* en langue anglaise] et son emploi antérieur le rend-il plutôt naturel en composition avec *propagande (computationnelle)* ?
- Le sens de l'adjectif [*informatique*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/informatique/42997?q=informatique#42902) est-il trop générique dans un tel contexte ; l'adjectif dérivé [*informatisé(e)*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/informatis%C3%A9/1) est-il plus utile ?
- Doit-on aller plus loin en employant une locution avec, par exemple, *basé(e) sur/adossé(e) à*, ou je ne sais trop, plutôt qu'un adjectif, afin de traduire tout apport qui sortirait du champ sémantique normal de l'équivalent de *par ordinateur* ; le fait que la définition identifie l'[*organisation de contenu*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26507071) (*human curation*) comme un élément-clé de la définition empêche-t-il de référer à l'*ordinateur* ou rend-il l'emploi d'un autre terme objectivement meilleur ?

Comment: Je pencherais pour (campagne de) 'Désinformation numérique' (un peut trop court pour une réponse complète)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR : **J'utiliserais propagande informatisée**.

---

> L'adjectif computationnel est-il apte à signifier ce dont il s'agit
>   [ou apte à jouer le même rôle que computational en langue anglaise] et
>   son emploi antérieur le rend-il plutôt naturel en composition avec
>   propagande (computationnelle) ?

[*computationnel*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/computationnel) ne me paraît pas être le terme le plus adapté dans ce cas. En effet, ce mot prend en compte des notions algébriques, de calcul (avec une machine), de démarche scientifique.

Je pense que la notion principale exprimée dans *computational propaganda* est le côté informatique : la propagande se fait au travers d'un écran d'ordinateur / par internet.

> Le sens de l'adjectif informatique est-il trop générique dans un tel
>   contexte ; l'adjectif dérivé informatisé(e) est-il plus utile ?

[*informatique*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/informatique/42997?q=informatique#42902) (qui relève de l'informatique), comme tu le dis à juste titre est peut-être trop générique.

Par contre, [*informatisé*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/informatiser/43001?q=informatis%C3%A9#42906) (utilisant des moyens informatiques, qui résout un problème par l'informatique) est le terme qui me paraît plus précis. 
 Premièrement car c'est un terme beaucoup plus courant que *computationnel*, et donc plus accessible, plus intelligible pour la majorité des gens. Secondement, il me paraît vraiment adéquat dans ce contexte : en le remplaçant par sa définition littérale, on obtient *propagande mise en place au travers de moyens informatiques*, ce qui correspond fidèlement à la définition de *computational propaganda*.

> Doit-on aller plus loin en employant une locution avec, par exemple,
>   basé(e) sur/adossé(e) à, ou je ne sais trop, plutôt qu'un adjectif,
>   afin de traduire tout apport qui sortirait du champ sémantique normal
>   de l'équivalent de par ordinateur ; le fait que la définition
>   identifie l'organisation de contenu (human curation) comme un
>   élément-clé de la définition empêche-t-il de référer à l'ordinateur ou
>   rend-il l'emploi d'un autre terme objectivement meilleur ?

J'aurais tendance à dire non, mais tout dépend du niveau de détail, de précision que tu souhaites poser derrière ce terme. À mon avis l'expression *propagande informatisée* est suffisamment claire, pas besoin de rentrer dans quelque chose de plus compliqué.

Comment: Merci ! Pour le dernier point vous aviez déjà répondu, essentiellement par _propagande mise en place au travers de moyens informatiques_, et c'est un verbe qui point (quel verbe bizarre) derrière informatisé. La nuance est de mise et l'idée de _précision_, quand on la désire, incontournable. Je ne sais pas si _computational_ est plus ou moins soutenu/usuel à dessein. Je ne sais pas si la référence aux algorithmes _ est entièrement rendue par le terme _informatisé_, mais la sémantique du mouvement d'_automation_ l'est sans doute par son aspect verbal contra l'adjectif. P.-ê. un truc en -able ?

Comment: @AgentBaptiste Le terme *propagande* ne permet-il pas à lui seul de prendre en compte cette notion d'*automatisme* et de *précision*?

Comment: Bonne question. C'est que l'apport de _computational_ à la lecture de la définition m'a semblé plus vaste que la manière d'effectuer la propagande, et à un moment donné je me suis demandé si c'est un apport ou vraiment une détermination qui finalement mène à qqc. d'autre. Même si c'était une forme de propagande ça ne signifierait pas nécessairement qu'on doive l'exprimer par un apport. Dans un article qui fait état des études on a des hésitations, je vois un cas où on met propagande entre guillemets et où on réfère directement aux « bots »,  « par bots » etc. Matière à réflexion. Merci !

Answer (score 2):

A partir de votre définition j'utiliserais:

> Une (campagne de) désinformation numérique

[Ici](http://data.over-blog-kiwi.com/1/52/74/42/20160720/ob_e52484_am-debat-numerique-digital-2016-vf.pdf) on trouve une intéressant analyse du glissmeent sémantique.

Je cite ici [wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Num%C3%A9rique) pour rester bref:

> Devenu substantif, « numérique » désigne maintenant les technologies
>   de l'information et de la communication,

Cela donne la traduction de `computational`, je préfère ce terme de numérique à celui de `digital` puisqu'en Français `digital` a déjà une signification de quelque chose en rapport avec le doigt (empreinte digitale par exemple)

Pour `propaganda` le terme littéral serait propagande, ce qui donnerait

> une propagande numérique

Cependant une propagande n'est pas forcément une mauvaise information, les communications de parti politique en période électorales sont une propagande.

C'est pourquoi j'y préfère ici le terme de `désinformation`, qui donne de fausse informations sciemment, qui parait plus en phase avec la définition anglaise.

La partie `campagne de` que je met entre parenthèse dépend en fait du sujet dans lequel l'expression est utilisée. Pour une généralité telle que celle ci:

> Ce compte twitter fait de la désinformation numérique

Le sujet est l'action générale de ce compte et non une action particulière. Dans l'exemple suivant on considère une action précise et non une façon d'agir en général.

> Il semblerait qu'une équipe de pirates soit la source de cette campagne de désinformation numérique

Comment: Merci d'avoir pris le temps de répondre !

Answer (score 0):

Globalement il s'agit:

1. D'influencer certains individus (ceux qui sont connectés), voire de les manipuler
2. via un point d'échange ("réseau social")
3. après une étude de leurs centres d'intérêts, préférences et opinions
4. réalisée par ordinateur, à partir des traces laissées par les individus
5. par une application basée sur les techniques d'intelligence artificielle (il ne s'agit pas de logique déterministe pre-programmée, mais de techniques d'apprentissage).

On ne peut pas exprimer tout cela dans une formule brève, et *computational propaganda* ne le fait pas, il se limite aux aspects 1 et 4. Pour une stricte traduction en se calquant sur les usages en français, je parlerais de :

`propagande informatisée`

- Propagande traduit exactement *propaganda*.
- Informatisé est en français l'adjectif qui signifie qu'il s'agit d'une opération effectuée via des ordinateurs (et donc des programmes, c'est-à-dire des calculs). L'alternative est "assisté(e) par ordinateur", comme dans CAO, PAO, GPAO, qui se substitue au *computer-assisted* de CAD, CAM, etc. Cette alternative laisse entendre que l'homme joue un rôle aussi, alors que "informatisé" laisse entendre que c'est entièrement automatique.

*Computationel* et *calculatoire* ne sont pas utilisés en France, c'est dommage car il insistent sur l'utilisation du programme (le *software*, les instructions particulières données à l'ordinateur) plutôt que sur celle du *hardware* qui est interchangeable, et donc ils seraient un meilleur choix, mais en français cette nuance n'est pas employée, on parle d'un traitement par ordinateur, ou informatique/informatisé.

Si au lieu de repartir de l'expression américaine, on essaie de trouver une formule plus exhaustive, on peut dire qu'il s'agit de la:

`propagande sur plateformes d'échange par analyse du comportement à l'aide de l'intelligence artificielle.`

En ce qui concerne l'utilisation de l'adjectif *numérique* (alors que j'écris cette réponse en 2020, ce buzzword est sur toutes les lèvres dans les entreprises): Numérique, traduction de l'anglais *digital*, est ambigu, tout comme l'est l'original. Numérique s'oppose à analogique, les premiers ordinateurs étaient analogiques, mais ont été très vite remplacés par des numériques basés sur les opérations binaires bien plus faciles à réaliser de façon fiable.

En 2020, dire qu'on fait appel à une technique numérique, c'est juste dire qu'on fait appel à l'informatique et [la révolution numérique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9volution_num%C3%A9rique) n'est que l'informatisation à tout-va.

Cependant, cette accélération n'est rendue possible, dans les domaines hier exclus où le jugement intervient, que par l'introduction de l'intelligence artificielle et, en ce sens, il y a effectivement une nouveauté. En tenant compte de cet élément, et en faisant l'hypothèse que le lecteur connait cette nuance, on a bien à faire à la :

`propagande sur plateformes d'échange par analyse numérique du comportement`

et en laissant de côté ce qui est sous-entendu (les plateformes Internet et leurs utilisateurs):

`propagande par analyse numérique du comportement`
ou plus bref `induction comportementale numérique`

ou si l'on se place du côté du manipulateur et de ceux qui font le commerce de la manipulation, l'euphémisme `interaction intelligente` (dans la veine des "smart something" sera acceptable, car dénué de tout sens précis.